# поиск подстроки в mysql

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения, like

можно ли в столбце из строки: **10,13,18/12:00:00/15:55:00**
извлечь первые 3 цифры до символа '**/**' ?
то есть мне надо что бы оператор LIKE сравнивал только (10,13,18), чисел может быть от 1 до 3

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен, использовал SUBSTRING_INDEX